# __str__ returned non-string (type NoneType) and deleting data from database

Tags: python, django

can anyone help me out with the problem am facing. Am trying to make a basic matrimony website where user can upload their profile and admin has to review it before appearing the website. first part uploading the details to  database it worked fine. I could able to add, modify , and delete . when I tried to add userForeignKey module to add user automatically i started facing this error  "**str** returned non-string (type NoneType)" and **it is deleting the entire data of that profile from the data base the moment I click on edit profile even before the form page opens and returning noneType** (before opening the form with instance its deleting the entire data ) and returning this error, all the data inside is just showing null in database. i tried uninstalling the module and reverted it back to to the same position where it worked before but unfortunately i  couldn't get it like before and am still facing the same issue.

here is my code :

MODEL:

```
class matrimony_db(models.Model):
    category = (
        ('MALE', 'Male'),
        ('FEMALE', 'Female'),
    )
    challenge =  (
        ('Yes', 'Yes'),
        ('No', 'No'),
    )
    ms =  (
        ('Single', 'Single'),
        ('Married', 'Married'),
        ('Divorced', 'Divorced'),
        ('widow', 'widow'),
        ('widower', 'widower'),
    )
    # personal details
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to = 'matrimony/')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null = True, blank = True)
    dob = models.DateField(null = True, blank = True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = category,null = True, blank = True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=50,null = True, blank = True)
    bio = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    # occupation and educations
    occupation = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null = True, blank = True)
    Highest_Education =  models.CharField(max_length = 500,null = True, blank = True)
    # physical details
    Height = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null = True, blank = True)
    weight = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null = True, blank = True)
    physical_challenge=models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = challenge,null = True, blank = True)
    Physical_remarks =  models.CharField(max_length = 500,null = True, blank = True)
    # PErsonal details
    Marital_status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices = ms,null = True, blank = True)
    Languages = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null = True, blank = True)
    currentplace = models.CharField(max_length = 200,null = True, blank = True)
    # Family details
    father = models.CharField(max_length=200,null = True, blank = True)
    mother = models.CharField(max_length=200,null = True, blank = True)
    mother_occupation = models.CharField(max_length=200,null = True, blank = True)
    father_occupation = models.CharField(max_length=200,null = True, blank = True)
    siblings = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)
    # psouse details
    spouse = models.TextField(null = True, blank = True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def delete(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.img.delete()
        super().delete(*args, **kwargs)
```

form:

```
class form_matrimony(forms.ModelForm):
    img = forms.ImageField(required=False)
    class Meta:
        model = matrimony_db
        fields = '__all__'
```

views : * note same code I used for other models for updating it works without any error dont know why this model only has that issue.

```
def view_update_matrimony(request, pk):
    book = matrimony_db.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = form_matrimony(instance=book)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        forms = form_matrimony(request.POST,request.FILES,instance = book )
        if forms.is_valid():
            forms.save()
            sb = str(book)
            messages.success(request, 'Files in ' +sb + " updated successfully")
            return redirect('admin_matrimony')
    else:
        form = form_matrimony()
    return render(request,'admin_loc_matrimony_new.html',{'form':form})
```

> NOTE : **after trying the methods typeerror doesnot appear but still
> data is getting deleted** [demonstration on how its getting added and
> rendering files till i click to edit and deleting files
> automatically **(video link)**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1xD7XIR438WTMQ9D3yBAP-W6otJVzn3at/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

Your `name` is a `NULL`able field. If it contains `NULL`, at the Django/Python level, this is `None`, and the `__str__` method is not supposed to return `None`. You can call the [**`str(…)`** builtin function [Python-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) on self.name` to return an item:

```
class matrimony_db(models.Model):
    # ⋮
    
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.name)
```

In your view, you should also initialize your form with the `book` instance:

```
def view_update_matrimony(request, pk):
    book = matrimony_db.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_matrimony(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=book)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            sb = str(book)
            messages.success(request, 'Files in ' +sb + " updated successfully")
            return redirect('admin_matrimony')
    else:
        #  with instance=book ↓           ↓
        form = form_matrimony(instance=book)
    return render(request,'admin_loc_matrimony_new.html',{ 'form':form })
```

You should also use `form` for the form in the POST request, not `forms` since then you will, for an invalid POST request, raise a `NameError`.

---

> **Note**: It is often better to use [**`get_object_or_404(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/shortcuts/#get-object-or-404),
> then to use [**`.get(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get) directly. In case the object does not exists,
> for example because the user altered the URL themselves, the `get_object_or_404(…)` will result in returning a *HTTP 404 Not Found* response, whereas using
> `.get(…)` will result in a *HTTP 500 Server Error*.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, my main problem is when i add data it perfectly getting stored in the database and i could able to render all the fields in to html  however when i want to update the the files and click on update link, its deleting all the fields automatically even before the form page opens and returning to nonetype.

Comment: @Ben: that is because you construct a `form_matrimony()` in the `else` case: you should construct it with the book instance (see answer edit).

Comment: Hi willem, i tried the methods u suggested , the error is no more rising but my main problem is still there (files getting deleted automatically. i have added an edit and placed a video link in note to demonstrate how exactly its getting deleted autmatically.

Comment: @Ben: you should make the file fields non-required. So specify `img = forms.ImageField(required=False)` in the `form_matrimony` class.

Comment: Hi Willem tried adding img field in form class but still it's deleting. The thing is if I edit from django admin panel it doesn't effect the fields but when  editing from user panel through function it's deleting all the fields in the table. When I tried to check step by step in views till form.is_valid() till then it works fine but when it reaches to form.save() it's effecting the fields. Don't know why it's happening like that :( same function when I use it to other tables it's working fine but only to matrimony_db table it's not working

Comment: @Ben: can you edit the question with how you updated the form?

Comment: @Ben: but it should not be part of the `Meta`, but of the `form_matrimony` class, so one indentation level more shallow.

Comment: Hi willem, i moved the img field to form class as i edited in the question. still the files are executing by itself as soon as i clink edit and getting deleted

Comment: Thank you willem , problem has been solved. i posted the answer.  its great help from you also in correcting the code :)

Answer (score 0):

it working now, when i have seperated this code

```
def view_update_matrimony(request, pk):
book = matrimony_db.objects.get(pk=pk)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = form_matrimony(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=book)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        sb = str(book)
        messages.success(request, 'Files in ' +sb + " updated successfully")
        return redirect('admin_matrimony')
else:
    #  with instance=book ↓           ↓
    form = form_matrimony(instance=book)
return render(request,'admin_loc_matrimony_new.html',{ 'form':form })
```

to two different functions

```
def view_update_matrimony(request, pk):
    book = matrimony_db.objects.get(pk=pk)
    form = form_matrimony(instance=book)
return render(request,'admin_loc_matrimony_new.html',{ 'form':form })

def update_matr(request,pk):
    book = matr_db.objects.get(pk=pk)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = form_matr(request.POST,request.FILES,instance = book )
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            sb = str(book)
            messages.success(request, 'Files in ' +sb + " updated successfully")
            return redirect('admin_others')
    else:
        form = form_matr(instance=book)
```

and used to different html one creating and second for displaying instance code with first functio to display and upload button calling second function from views to save and added the urls according to it.

> **main problem appears to be with form.is_valid() and  form.save() in the first function which is executing while bypassing the if condition(request.method == 'POST') without sending the request . Which i have no idea why its working like that.  My best guess was when  i click edit , the html page which has form tag with post method is sending the unsaved data even before loading the instance and executing the if request.method condition and saving the empty fields which receiving from html file. when i have seperated the save function it has no where to send empty fields thus allowing me to load the instance to all field and allowing me to save with second function.**